# MUI: Horizontal Alignment of Checkbox and FormLabel

Tags: material-ui

I have a Checkbox and FormLabel that are within the same component that I'd like to horizontally align next to each other.

Component

```
return (
            <Wrapper>
                <StyledFormGroup>
                    <StyledFormLabel></StyledFormLabel>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={(
                        <Checkbox

                        />
                        )}
                        label={<Typography className="">Yes</Typography>}
                        labelPlacement="end"
                    />
                </StyledFormGroup>
            </EftAuthorizationWrapper>
        );
```

CSS

```
export const Wrapper = styled("div")`
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 280px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 288px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
`;

export const StyledFormGroup = styled(FormGroup)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0px;
`;

export const StyledFormLabel = styled(FormLabel)`
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
`;
```

Locally tested - changing the CSS did not change it. The styling seems to be around the control label.